# DBSetup - How to do a select statement

Tags: java, dbsetup

I was looking in to DBUnit for sometime until a nice chap on here pointed me to some application he made named DBSetup that was more light weight and easy.

I must admit 1) I have found it useful so far (only 2 hours in) but testing without xml seems a joy.

However - I am now at the stage where I need to do a select from the database to ensure data consistency - I don't however see this option in the API

Would someone be able to inform me how I would do this? I was expecting to see a Select select = Select.from or something of this nature as has been done for the inserts

```
Insert insert = Insert.into("Users")...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DbSetup doesn't have this functionality. As said in its home page: *[it] focuses on a single task: populate the database with test data.*

Since the goal of DbSetup is to help you populate the database with test data to let you test data access code, you should use your data access code to get the data from the database.